# Replace values displayed on the command line

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line, multidimensional-array, user-input

I have a java code that displays elements of a 2 dimensional array on the command line like this:

```
    Boy      Girl
    Tom      Jane
    John     Beth
```

Is there a way to allow a user to delete Tom and replace it with Ben or even leave it Blank.
I tried to use BufferedReader, but I can only use it to read from a different line and not replace a value that is already displayed.

Comment: You can't go back and "edit" output that is printed to the console.

Comment: Considering it's a console you can display the data with a small menu of needed actions. Use the action and the data against your data structure. Then you can clear the console screen and rebuild it with the new info.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ... try [JLine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jline/).  It says "JLine is a java library for reading and editing user input in console applications" so maybe you can get it to work as you wish.